# How do I catch AuthHttpError when making a request with AuthHttp?

Tags: angular, typescript, authhttp

I'm having an issue being able to catch the `AuthHttpError` that gets returned from calls to `AuthHttp`in `angular2-jwt`.

Whenever `AuthHttp` detects that the token is expired, it will throw `AuthHttpError` without sending the request to the backend.  I would like to catch this error so I can log out the user.  However, I can't seem to be able to catch this in `Observable.catch()`.

Let's say I have code like this:

```
doRequest(url: string, params: string, jsonOptions: string) {
  return this.http.post(url, params, jsonOptions)
      .catch(response => {
          if (response instanceof Response) {
              console.info('handle server errors');
          } else if (response instanceof AuthHttpError) {
              console.info('handle AuthHttpError');
          } else {
             console.info('handle other Error')
          }
          return Observable.throw(response);
      })
}
```

In this case, if the token has expired, I want the console to print "handle AuthHttpError", but it will print "handle other Error" instead.  I also noticed that in this case, `response.constructor.name` will be "Error" instead of "AuthHttpError".

Does anyone know if there's a way to catch this error?